# JLabel wont change when i run from command line

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I have an interface for a sqlite db. Everything works except two JLabels wont display what they are supposed to. It runs in netbeans with no exceptions. But when i run it from command line it does not setText to the JLabels and only these two JLabels(vanOil & VanTires). Anyone have any clue why?

```
public class MaintenanceDB {
    String van = (String) TabbedPane.chooseVan.getSelectedItem();

    public void checkVan() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:office.sqlite");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat
                .executeQuery("Select * from Maintenance WHERE Van IS " + van
                        + ";");

        int totalMiles = Integer.parseInt(TabbedPane.vanMiles.getText());
        int lastOil = rs.getInt("LastOilChange");
        int lastTire = rs.getInt("LastTireRotation");
        int tireIndex = 5;
        int oilIndex = 5;
        int nextTire = lastTire + tireIndex;
        int nextOil = lastOil + oilIndex;
        boolean checkOil = CheckMaintenance.checkOil(totalMiles, nextOil);
        boolean checkTire = CheckMaintenance.checkTire(totalMiles, nextTire);
        int oilDiff = Math.abs(nextOil - totalMiles);
        int tireDiff = Math.abs(nextTire - totalMiles);
        String displayOil = van + " not due for oil change for " + oilDiff
                + " miles.";
        String displayTire = van + " not due for tire totation for " + tireDiff
                + " miles.";
        if (checkOil) {
            displayOil = "**Van " + van + " " + oilDiff
                    + " miles overdue for oil change**";
        }
        if (checkTire) {
            displayTire = "**Van " + van + " " + tireDiff
                    + " miles overdue for tire rotation*";
        }
        rs.close();

        conn.close();
        TabbedPane.vanOil.setText(displayOil);
        TabbedPane.vanTires.setText(displayTire);

    }
}
```

****EDIT*****************

```
    if(command.equals(TabbedPane.setMiles.getText())){

             try {
            MaintenanceDB mdb=new MaintenanceDB();
          mdb.checkVan();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(CallsEvent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

    }
```

Comment: I would guess your classpath is wrong and you are throwing and Exception somewhere, probably on the Database query.

Comment: show client code where you call this method

Comment: all the information is stored in the same database. The other methods access the database and read and write to and from it fine. Its just this one. I checked the action listener to make sure that the button click actually performs something... and i will edit my code to include where i call the method

Comment: mm try catching throwable to test, are you sure that your logger log ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines of code

```
System.out.println( "displayOil :" + displayOil );
```

just after you create each variable. You'll know if your code gets until there.

If the message is not output to the console, then an exception is interrupting your code.

Otherwise, your method has a

```
throws Exception
```

declaration. this is not good code practice since we don't know anything from what exceptions the method can throw (therefore, where it could have issues). You should rather be more specific in your exception declaration: eg.

```
throws JDBCException, BusinessException
```

that way, you know what to expect from it. Also, never do a

```
catch(Exception ex) {}
```

you can loose hours and days of debugging because of this line (depending on the size of your project). If you really don't know what to do, either write to stack trace of rethrow a RTex passing it the original cause exception

```
throw new RuntimeException("don't know what to do here", ex);
```

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi - http://1vu.fr

Comment: thank you for the help. I was able to narrow down the problem using the println. I had the absolute file path stored in a variable and for some reason didnt use it here. Even though the relative path should have worked since its in the main dir...changing it to the absolute path fixed the problem.